How to make a Spring AI ETL File Supplier delete files as it goes
How can I configure the File Supplier to delete, or move files after processing each file?
The full code may be found here: https://github.com/ByteworksHomeLab/spring-ai-lab
After loading test data from a CSV file and producing 60+ JSON files containing JSON Arrays, I manually kick off the ETL workflow when a REST endpoint calls this method:
    public void ingest() {
        Runnable composedFunction = catalog.lookup(null);
        composedFunction.run();
    }

As each JSON file is processed, I want it moved or deleted.
Here is the ETL configuration.
spring:
  cloud:
    function:
      definition: fileSupplier|documentReader|documentTransformer|vectorStoreConsumer

Here are the functions:
@Configuration
public class CloudFunctionConfig {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CloudFunctionConfig.class);

    public static String asString(Object value) {
        String valueString = "";
        if (value != null) {
            valueString += value.toString();
        }
        return valueString;
    }

    public Document convertJsonNodeToListing(JsonNode jsonNode) {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Listing listing = objectMapper.convertValue(jsonNode, Listing.class);
        return new Document(
                listing.name() + " - " + listing.description(),
                Map.of(
                        "id", listing.id(),
                        "name", listing.name(),
                        "description", listing.description(),
                        "listingUrl", listing.listingUrl(),
                        "price", listing.price(),
                        "propertyType", listing.propertyType(),
                        "neighborhood", listing.neighbourhood(),
                        "bedrooms", asString(listing.bedrooms()),
                        "bathrooms", asString(listing.bathrooms())
                )
        );
    }

    @Bean
    Function<Flux<byte[]>, Flux<Document>> documentReader() {
        return resourceFlux -> resourceFlux.flatMap(fileBytes -> {
            try {
                ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
                JsonNode rootNode = objectMapper.readTree(fileBytes);
                if (rootNode.isArray()) {
                    // Convert each element of the JSON array into a Document
                    return Flux.fromIterable(rootNode::elements).map(this::convertJsonNodeToListing);
                } else {
                    // If it's not an array, treat the whole content as a single document
                    return Flux.just(convertJsonNodeToListing(rootNode));
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                log.error("documentReader error", e);
                return Flux.error(new RuntimeException("Failed to parse JSON", e));
            }
        }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic());
    }

    @Bean
    Function<Flux<Document>, Flux<List<Document>>> documentTransformer() {
        return documentsFlux -> documentsFlux.map(incoming -> new TokenTextSplitter().apply(List.of(incoming))).subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic());
    }

    @Bean
    Consumer<Flux<List<Document>>> vectorStoreConsumer(VectorStore vectorStore) {
        return documentFlux -> documentFlux.doOnNext(vectorStore).subscribe();
    }
}

